# Local Angular schematics

Tags: angular, angular-schematics

I have a project where I want to automate routine operations using Angular schematics. However, I could only find examples which require building schematics as a separate library.

Is there any way to have the schematics as a part of the project and not have it built even locally?

Just the same way you don't create a local library to share a component within the project I want my schematic to be.